# To assign an Id to every step in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I am looking for ways to group steps in cucumber, is it possible to attach an id to every step?

Answer (score 0):

An unique ID is already attached by [`PickleStepTestStep`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-core/4.7.2/cucumber/api/PickleStepTestStep.html) at runtime . One way to get is through plugin like below

```
    import io.cucumber.plugin.EventListener;
    import io.cucumber.plugin.event.*;
    
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.TreeMap;
    import java.util.UUID;
    
    public class    ReportPlugin implements EventListener {
    
     private final Map<String, UUID> startedSteps = new TreeMap<String, UUID>();
     private final Map<String, Status> finishedCases = new TreeMap<String, Status>();
    
       @Override
        public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
            
            publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, this::handleTestStepStarted);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseFinished.class, this::handleTestCaseFinished);

        }
    
    private void handleTestStepStarted(TestStepStarted event) {
            startedSteps.put(event.getTestStep().toString(), event.getTestStep().getId());
            for (Map.Entry<String, UUID> entry : startedSteps.entrySet()) {
                    String location = entry.getKey();
                    UUID uuid = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println(location + " ###fromTestStepStarted### " + uuid);
            
             //above prints
            //io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep@5a5c128 ###fromTestStepStarted### 7f964f1c-9442-43fc-97e9-9ec6717eb47f
           // io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep@77b919a3 ###fromTestStepStarted### a5d57753-aecb-40a0-a0cf-76bef7526dd8

                }
        }

      //If you would like to get each test step text you do this

    private void handleTestCaseFinished(TestCaseFinished event) {
        
        
        TestCase testCase = event.getTestCase();
        String scenarioName = testCase.getName();

        TestStep testStep = testCase.getTestSteps().get(0);
        if (testStep instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
            PickleStepTestStep pickleStepTestStep  = (PickleStepTestStep) testStep;
            String text = pickleStepTestStep.getStep().getText();
            System.out.println("****Pickle Step TestStep*****"+  text);

           //above prints
          //****Pickle Step TestStep*****I open the site ""  
            }

      
        }

   }
```

To run the above class - put the class with your step defs  or your supporting classes and then in `junit-platform.properties` (for Junit5) mention plugin like this

`cucumber.plugin =  com.test.support.ReportPlugin`

For Junit4 you might have to add plugin to your runner class

When you run your tests you should see everything printed on console

Comment: Yeah, I want to group multiple steps to an Id.  For that this will not work